# puts() questions with const char

Tags: c, pointers, puts

I'm having trouble understanding how c uses puts() to display parts of a message. Two ways which I would consider equivalent do not work the same way with the function. For example

```
 void skippie(char *msg)
 {
    puts(msg + 6);
 }

 char *msg = "Don't call me!";
 skippie(msg);
```

This compiles fine, however this does not

```
void skippie(char *msg)
{
    puts(msg[6]);
}

char *msg = "Don't call me!";
skippie(msg);
```

how does puts() distinguish between the two and only compile for one? The compiler complains that it wants a "const" char but even if I try and use that syntax it fails. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: `msg[6]` is the same as `*(msg + 6)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index operator also dereferences the pointer, so

`msg[6]` is equivalent to `*(msg + 6)`, not `msg + 6`.

Furthermore, you cannot pass a `const char*` to a function, while it expects a `char*`. i.e., you also have to update the function signature.

Answer (score 0):

`msg + 6` is not the same as `msg[6].`

As per your code, `msg+6` is a `char *`, while `msg[6]` represents a `char`.

Quoting from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/puts) of `puts()`, the syntax is

```
int puts(const char *s);
```

so, the argument of `puts()` needs to be a `const char *`, not a `char`.